# Using logged in userid(foreign_key) for fillling out form in oneToMany mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am working on spring-mvc application which uses Spring Security to login and hibernate as the ORM tool. So, my project only has 2 tables, Table Person has OneToMany mapping with Table Notes. So, once the user is logged into the system, he/she should be able to add notes, but while adding I would like to also save the Person's id, which is why I have used to OneToMany mapping. But I don't know how to get user's id and put it in the form. Below is my code.

The error is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "personid" violates not-null constraint
```

Which is understandable, thats why I want to know how I can retreive the personid.

Person model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="personid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person1")
    private Set<Notes> notes1;
}
```

Note model :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="note")
public class Notes {

    @Id
    @Column(name="noteid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "note_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "note_gen",sequenceName = "note_seq")
    private int noteId;

  @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "personid")
   private Person person1;
}
```

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE public.person (
                personid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                firstname VARCHAR,
                username VARCHAR,
                password VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (personid)
);


CREATE TABLE public.note (
                noteid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                sectionid INTEGER,
                canvasid INTEGER,
                text VARCHAR,
                notecolor VARCHAR,
                noteheadline VARCHAR,
                personid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT noteid PRIMARY KEY (noteid)
);


ALTER TABLE public.note ADD CONSTRAINT user_note_fk
FOREIGN KEY (personid)
REFERENCES public.person (personid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Person controller :

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }


    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){


            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }
```

NoteController :

```
@Controller
public class NoteController {



    private NotesService notesService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="notesService")
    public void setNotesService(NotesService notesService){this.notesService=notesService;}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/notes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listNotes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("notes", new Notes());
        model.addAttribute("listnotes", this.notesService.listNotes());
        return "notes";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value= "/note/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addNote(@ModelAttribute("notes") Notes p){
        this.notesService.addNote(p);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Note.jsp (here is where I add notes.)

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/note/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="notes">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty notes.note}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="noteid">
                        <spring:message text="noteid"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="noteid" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="noteid" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="note">
                    <spring:message text="note"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="note" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="notetag">
                    <spring:message text="notetag"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="notetag" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="notecolor">
                    <spring:message text="notecolor"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="notecolor" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="canvasid">
                    <spring:message text="canvasid"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="canvasid" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="sectionid">
                    <spring:message text="sectionid"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="sectionid" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <c:if test="${!empty notes.note}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit note"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty notes.note}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add note"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but when there is a logged in user (Principal) in a thread then you can just use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` to get the Principal or just inject it using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` or just make sure your Person implements Principal interface and inject it directly (I assume a Person is a User and a User is a Principal) to get the person.id.

In /note/add try like this:

```
public String addNote(@ModelAttribute("notes") Notes p, @AuthenticationPrincipal Person person)) {
    p.setPerson1(person);
    this.notesService.addNote(p);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

If you want to avoid setting it manually consider usage of AuditorAware and Auditable like here:
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-auditing-code-example.html

Comment: Yes, Person is the User, but Person implements UserDetails, not Principal interface.Do I need to pass that to JSP page, as when I am trying to use /note/add in URL, it says it doesn't have personId.

Comment: It worked, I am getting org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing, but I will find the solution.

Comment: Yes it is a pure persistence issue right now that a person should be already persisted in database before an attempt to save a note.